# Getting duplicate value in sql

Tags: sql

Query is below:

```
select 
    C.ngo_seq_no, B.member_name, B.member_pan_no, B.member_aadhar_no,
    C.dept_name, C.source, C.fin_year, C.amt_sanctioned, C.comment, 
    R.member_designation_desc 
from  
    member_designation R, ngo_member_detail B 
inner join
    ngo_source_fund C on B.ngo_seq_no = C.ngo_seq_no  
where 
    mem_designation = member_designation_id::text  
    and C.ngo_seq_no = '15' ;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. And **most definitely** don't mix that legacy style with `inner join` in the same query!!

Comment: Duplicate values are often caused by a duplicate in one of the joined tables - which we cannot see because you didn't provide any data

Answer (score 0):

15;"Sanjay";"43537459874";"346555378895";"Nic";"2";"29922";"Nothing"
15;"Sanjay";"43537459874";"346555378895";"Nic";"2";"29922";"Nothing"
15;"Sanjay";"43537459874";"346555378895";"Nic";"2";"29922";"Nothing"
15;"Ajay ";"587592894832";"646738972456";"Nic";"2";"29922";"Nothing"
15;"Ajay ";"587592894832";"646738972456";"Nic";"2";"29922";"Nothing"
15;"Ajay ";"587592894832";"646738972456";"Nic";"2";"29922";"Nothing"
15;"Rahul";"4353745983";"346732856575";"Nic";"2";"29922";"Nothing"
15;"Rahul";"4353745983";"346732856575";"Nic";"2";"29922";"Nothing"
15;"Rahul";"4353745983";"346732856575";"Nic";"2";"29922";"Nothing"